# Create a temporary table in temporary tablespace db2

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a way to create a system The table was not created because the table space "TEMPTB" following the clause "IN" is a "SYSTEM TEMPORARY" table space.  SQLSTATE=42838

This is the error I keep getting when I create a temp table in a temp tablespace...does db2 not support it? because oracle does.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Temporary tablespaces are used only for system-created temporary objects – for joins, sorts that are too large for the sort heap, table queues that overflow, etc.

You need to create a `USER TEMPORARY` tablespace.  You can [read more](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0052067.html) about the various types of tablespaces.  And use the `CREATE TABLESPACE` command to [create one](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0055364.html).